# Cancel substr on hover

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have list:

```
<section class="last-content">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <img src="temp/person-1.png" alt="">
        <span class="name">Natali</span>
        <span class="post">director</span>
        <span class="text">Text text text text text text text text text text text </span>
        <a href="#?" class="more">more</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

Several elements (li).

Default code jquery:

```
 $(".last-content .text").each(function(a){
      len=$(this).text().length;

      if(len>107)
      {
        $(this).text($(this).text().substr(0,107)+'...');
      }

    });

   $('.last-content ul li').on('hover', function() {

    .......???
     .text must be full

   });
```

This code makes the text selector(.text) short.

After function "hover" must do a full text selector(.text).

How to do it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Don't do it like this!

First of all, when you replace the text content of the element, you lose the reference of the original. You would have to store somehow in order to restitue it back.

But css has a feature meant to add (...) when a text overflows a specified size, like this:

```css
span.text:not(:hover) {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<section class="last-content">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <img src="temp/person-1.png" alt="">
        <span class="name">Natali</span>
        <span class="post">director</span>
        <span class="text">Text text text text text text text text text text text </span>
        <a href="#?" class="more">more</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a lot of texts to store you can also instead of doing a substr(), replace the cut portion with a cut part and hide that span so when you do the hover, you can show the span.

For example:

```
<span class="text">Text too long_bla bla</span>
```

would be

```
<span class='text'> Text to...<span class='cut'>o long bla bla </span></span>
```